# Deploying on Heroku shows wrong codebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have a fully developed app folder (Rails) that's been pushed to staging and prod using Heroku. I copy-pasted it and then renamed the folder, so I can have a second similar app with a different name. Then from terminal, I went to the new folder and created a new Heroku staging environment.

When I pushed in that new folder using `heroku push staging main`, it pushed to the original folder's staging environment.

When I looked via `git remote v-`, I saw the original folder's environments. So I added git for that new staging environment in that new folder, using `git remote add`. That worked.

Now I came back to the original folder (because I still have to develop a bit more and maintain it). There I pushed to staging via `heroku push staging main`. It didn't work, so I followed this:

```bash
git fetch origin master:tmp
git rebase tmp
git push origin HEAD:master
git branch -D tmp
```

Then I could push as usual to the original folder's staging environment.

**BUT** for some reason, when I go to that original staging url, I see the new folder codebase reflected (with different names and such that I edited).

I've searched but couldn't find the answer. What's going on? Thank you in advance.

Comment: So I can tell (I think) following those fetch steps (from SO) resulted in replacing the original folder's git with with the new folder's. If that's the case, how do I revert this?

Comment: That's a very messy way to do it. Next time fork your orginal project and change the remotes at the same time. Github lets you do this with a button push. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo